# How to know which application uses my clipboard?

Tags: windows, clipboard

On my Windows XP, I have problems with my clipboard. Sometimes I Copy and nothing goes in the clipboard. And nothing is pasted.

Excel gives me such errors : `The clipboard cannot be emptied. Another program might be using the clipboard.`   But not always, sometimes it works.

How can I find which program seems to be constantly dealing with my clipboard?
With SysInternals tools or any other tool?

Comment: Does event viewer give any indication?

Comment: @Fredv Is Skype installed on your PC? Take a look on this [article](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/cannont-empty-clipboard/).

Comment: Any chance it is a virus/malware?

Comment: No, Skype is not installed. McAfee seems to prevent correctly malwares

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a tool exists for Windows (all versions), so in case not, these are things you can try.

Since OP is on XP (and I don't think this works after XP), there is a tool in `c:\windows\system32\` folder called `clipbrd.exe` which can show you.

Many people experience such issues due to either Skype, or the IE/Firefox/Chrome plugin for Skype. Try removing them both and see if the issue persists (or not).

Some people experience this when Outlook is open. Just restarting Outlook can resolve the issue.

Although the OP is on XP, some users on W7 experience this when the Snipping Tool is in use.

It also occurs whilst using RDP so close that down.

Lastly, it is because something else is monitoring the clipboard process, but this would typically be tools you've installed so you either know of them, or your IT department does.

Comment: I have launched clipbrd.exe : i will check that. I'm using Outlook and i can't stop it too often :)   and i'm also using RDP. I will try to find which one is the problem